# Handling Routing Exception in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am studying ruby on rails now and got stuck in exception handling. I just try to handle routing exceptions. I followed the following article
https://coderwall.com/p/whjmra/handling-exceptions-in-your-rails-application

In the code,  id din't got the method 'render_exception(404, "Routing Error", exception)' . Please help me for this. I need to show my 404 page which is in the errors\404 in the view folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you handle exception try:

```
render :file => 'errors/404.html', :status => :not_found, :layout => false
```